# Hierarchical structures: fixed effects estimations - how to choose which fixed effects to include?

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

How to choose cross-sectional units when estimating fixed effects?

I have flight delays as the dependent variable and my data consists of 15 airlines, thus, multiple aircraft. Initially, I thought to use aircraft or carriers as cross-sectional units and thus consider the aircraft's/carriers' fixed effect. Both estimations gave similar results.
However, I also tried to consider itineraries as cross-sectional units: the estimates were considerably larger. So I was wondering what I should stick to: carrier, airline, or itineraries fixed effect. Particularities of dataset: 15 airlines (average number of time periods: 10000), 4000 aircraft (average number of time periods: 175), and 25000 itineraries (average number of time periods: 5).

Comment: Can you elaborate on your research question and what information you want out of your model?

Comment: @ErikRuzek the question was more like a simple example of hierarchical structure. I have a different research set-up, I just thought it is easier to use a commonly used example. Regarding my particular research, I have flight delays as the dependent variable and my data consists of 15 airlines, thus, multiple aircraft. Initially, I thought to use aircraft or carriers as cross-sectional units and thus consider the aircraft's/carriers' fixed effect. Both estimations gave similar results.(see next comment)

Comment: @ErikRuzek  However, I also tried to consider itineraries as cross-sectional units: the estimates were considerably larger. So I was wondering what I should stick to: carrier, airline, or itineraries fixed effect. Particularities of dataset: 15 airlines (average number of time periods: 10000), 4000 aircraft (average number of time periods: 175), and 25000 itineraries (average number of time periods: 5).

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a key predictor or two that you are focused on. If so, at what level is it measured at?

Comment: @ErikRuzek For example, I use buffer time as one of the predictors, which varies per airline and per distance traveled (so, per flight). I also use a degree of the airport, which also depends on the arrival airport (thus again, per flight).

Comment: @ErikRuzek For example, if I choose $i$ to represent aircraft and use $t$ to represent the order/sequence of flights, the model is as follows: $Y_{}=_{i}+Z_{}+$ where $Z_{it}$ is e.g. degree of arrival airport for flight $t$ performed by aircraft $i$.

Comment: I would suggest that you add the information in the comments to your original post. It is hard to answer general questions such as the one you posed because so much about modeling is a mixture of general rules/ideas and peculiarities related to your data and research question.